# Parsing PHP array which has an abject inside

Tags: php, solr

I've got a response form the solr query in php. below is the response form apache solr in drupal6, i need to access the id field inside the Apache_Solr_Document, can some bosy help me with this.

i was able to print this using **print_r($result);**

Array ( [type] => Bookmarks [node] => Apache_Solr_Document Object (  [_documentBoost:protected] => [_fields:protected] => Array (  [id] => b17692e4ad53/node/274 )))

if i do **print_r($result[node]);** i am getting

Apache_Solr_Document Object (  [_documentBoost:protected] => [_fields:protected] => Array (  **[id]** => b17692e4ad53/node/274 ))

from here i can't figure out how to access the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried reading through [IBM's article on Solr](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-apachesolr/#php)?  The end of the article deals specifically with PHP.

Edit: After finding a [source class](http://cvs.drupal.org/viewvc.py/drupal/contributions/modules/apachesolr/SolrPhpClient/Apache/Solr/Document.php?r1=1.1&r2=1.2) to read through, it looks like you can do:

```
$result['node']->getField("id");
```

or using the magic __get:

```
$result['node']->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the {} brackets if the object name is not a valid object property name (like SimpleXML stuff).

```
$object->{'strang&$*#nmame'}->value;
```

Comment: @pmarreddy Make that an answer.